# Highcharts Backgroundimage for bar graph

Tags: css, uiwebview, background-image, highcharts, bar-chart

I want to add a background image to a bar chart using Highcharts and display it in a `UIWebView`.

So far I've been using this little plugin, which is working fine in latest Chrome.
However, as soon as I load this into my UIWebView, the image is not displayed.
I think this is related to the fact that iOS might not be able to parse the correct path for the image file?

Is there another (simpler) way to just add a background-image to a bar chart?

**In my Highcharts data series**

```
color: {
   pattern: 'static/img/theimage.png',
   width: 160,
   height: 500
}
```

**The plugin**

```
/**
 * Highcharts pattern fill plugin
 */
(function() {
    var idCounter = 0,
        base = Highcharts.Renderer.prototype.color;

    Highcharts.Renderer.prototype.color = function(color, elem, prop) {
        if (color && color.pattern && prop === 'fill') {
            // SVG renderer
            if (this.box.tagName == 'svg') {
                var id = 'highcharts-pattern-'+ idCounter++;
                var pattern = this.createElement('pattern')
                        .attr({
                            id: id,
                            patternUnits: 'userSpaceOnUse',
                            width: color.width,
                            height: color.height
                        })
                        .add(this.defs),
                    image = this.image(
                        color.pattern, 0, 0, color.width, color.height
                    )
                    .add(pattern);
                return 'url(' + this.url + '#' + id + ')';

            // VML renderer
            } else {
                var markup = ['<', prop, ' type="tile" src="', color.pattern, '" />'];
                elem.appendChild(
                    document.createElement(this.prepVML(markup))
                );                
            }

        } else {
            return base.apply(this, arguments);
        }
    };    
})();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem in that my iPad wasn't showing up my gradient background.

I solved this in the end by putting backgroundColor: null, in my JS and using a CSS3 gradient on the ID and declaring the height of the DIV.  This would most probably work with a background image as well.

Comment: yeah I think it should , check grid css files