# use image to fill bars in highchart?

Tags: highcharts

Can we use an image pattern to fill the bar of highchart barcharts.?

In this link http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-negative/
the bars are colored as blue,maroon and green but what i am looking for is to fill them with an image which i have.Is it doable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Borrowing from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10982137/highcharts-backgroundimage-for-bar-graph), I've put together a demostration [here](http://jsfiddle.net/c9zYu/1/).

Using one of the original Google doodles:

[image]

Comment: hey image is not visible in JS fiddle . can you please suggest here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49526794/create-dynamic-graph-with-image-pattern]