# How to add a background image (pattern) to highchart column graph?

Tags: highcharts, background-image

i'm using highcharts.js for the first time. seems great and powerful, i've enjoyed it thus far.

i'm trying, however, to get my column graph to look a bit sexier and am having trouble finding the information as to how i can do this, at least in regards to using a repeating background image for the column.

here's what i had designed: [image]

Comment: I don't think that is currently an option - see api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.bar

Comment: ya, been browsing through their stuff all day with no luck. was hoping someone would know something i didn't :\ thanks-

Comment: Try to set up your background manually using raw svg. It's the most convenient option.

Comment: For example, $('some_selector').after(chart.renderer.image(imageToAdd, 0, 0, 50, 30).element) will render image for you.

Comment: that's really interesting. i've never done any svg work before so it'll be new to me. problem is that it's a super quick turnaround so time to explore isn't really available at the moment. once i get a few other to-do's checked off i'll revisit this and see what i can accomplish. thanks for the lead!

Comment: i've tried seeing if their api offers a way of doing this. the issue is that it doesn't and it's rendered via SVG, something i've not dealt with before. @kreig's suggestion looks promising, i just haven't had time to follow up with it as of yet

Comment: @JohnBlythe did you see the answer of this question, it might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11841120/use-image-to-fill-bars-in-highchart. Also check out the image example of the api, it shows you how to add an image to chart, http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/renderer-image-on-chart/

Comment: brooooo, that first one is money. i haven't tried it yet, but it looks like exactly what i need. i had only found one other question on here like mine and it was never answered, must've been b/c i was searching with "background-image" primarily. i'll test it out momentarily and get back to you. post as an answer so i can accept it, please

Comment: and it worked, btw. put it in an answer form, please, so i can accept it for your rep and people looking in the future. thanks again!

Comment: Take look also for this example: http://jsfiddle.net/Kr82z/1/

Comment: @SebastianBochan, that's the exact code/example from the support guy from Highcharts. he just posted it again below, too.

Answer (score 4):

You can add patterns by using this

```
      color: {
                pattern: 'https://rawgithub.com/highslide-software/pattern-fill/master/graphics/pattern3.png',
                width: 6,
                height: 6
            }
```

Modify accordingly to suit your needs in seriesData

**Demo** - [Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/ErU8H/)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just for the reference, I replied to the same question on Highcharts forum (http://highslide.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=25673)

First of all, there was an idea of using pattern fill for columns. Basic demo was posted on Highcharts Uservoice site (http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general/suggestions/2378007-allow-fill-patterns-for-areas-columns-plot-bands).

You can improve that code to create SVG pattern with gradient fill. The main difficulty is support for data updates (and animations). Because of this we can't define fixed width for gradient element. See the sample code below:

```
Highcharts.Renderer.prototype.color = function (color, elem, prop) {

    if (color && color.pattern && prop === 'fill') {
        // SVG renderer
        if (this.box.tagName == 'svg') {
            var patternA,
                patternB,
                bgColor,
                bgPattern,
                image,
                id;

            id = 'highcharts-pattern-' + idCounter++;

            patternA = this.createElement('pattern')
            .attr({
                id: id,
                patternUnits: 'userSpaceOnUse',
                width: '100%',
                height: '100%'
            })
            .add(this.defs);

            patternB = this.createElement('pattern')
            .attr({
                id: id + '-image',
                patternUnits: 'userSpaceOnUse',
                width: color.width,
                height: color.width
            })
            .add(this.defs);

            image = this.image(color.pattern, 0, 0, 6, 6)
            .add(patternB);


            bgColor = this.rect(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
            .attr({
                fill: color.fill,
                width: '100%',
                height: '100%'
            })
            .add(patternA);


            bgPattern = this.rect(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
            .attr({
                fill: 'url(' + this.url + '#' + id + '-image)',
                width: '100%',
                height: '100%'
            })
            .add(patternA);

            return 'url(' + this.url + '#' + id + ')';

            // VML renderer
        } else {
            var markup = ['<', prop, ' type="tile" src="', color.pattern, '" />'];
            elem.appendChild(
            document.createElement(this.prepVML(markup)));
        }

    } else {
        return base.apply(this, arguments);
    }
};
```

Live demo available here: http://jsfiddle.net/Kr82z/

Comment: i appreciate the help. i'd seen the post on the forums and went to reply but that was when they disabled the forums :\ i've got the pattern portion down, it's the gradient AND pattern that is my current issue. unless i'm misunderstanding your post it doesn't seem like that's a good, viable option, is it?

Comment: Unfortunately this is the simplest solution I came up with. Two another are:

1) Create images with gradient, pattern and glow and position it to the top of each column. Image should be as high as chart, so it could be clipped.
2) Get to know with SVG "use" element (http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#UseElement) and render separate elements for gradient or pattern.