# Putting image as bar in bar charts. Is it possible?

Tags: d3.js, charts, highcharts, bar-chart, amcharts

In Microsoft Office 2016 we can place image as bar in bar charts which looks like something below;
[image]

Can we do something similar using any of the charting library like AmCharts, HighCharts or d3.js?

I searched it all there in the internet and didn't came across any kind of recommendations or solutions.

Anyone here got any idea on the same?. Your inputs are well appreciated.

I achieved something in AmCharts using patterns which looks like something below;
[image]

But I don't need the image to be repeating inside the bar rather it should be displayed same as bar which shows the value definition. Is it possible with any of the charting library?.

Comment: You could do this in highcharts, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11841120/use-image-to-fill-bars-in-highchart

Comment: But the example fiddle is not working in the above thread.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that, it is an old answer. That said, it should work quite similarly still. So if you look around in the API it should be possible to figure out. This probably helps as well: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/gradients-shadows-and-patterns

Comment: Also possible in d3.js though requires quite a bit of custom path work [blocks](https://bl.ocks.org/vigorousnorth/f483171a617a5c6bb6d5). This is in d3 version 3 but the same idea can be used in v4

Comment: I confirm that the solution proposed by @ewolden (Highcharts defs) will work.

Comment: But If I used it as a pattern the image will be shown as repeated right?. I want something similar I shown above. The image should define the bar values.