# Create dynamic graph with image pattern

Tags: javascript, graph, charts, highcharts

is it possible to create this graph using any java script api .

[image: pencil graph]

I really got stuck where to and in what direction I should start and it should be dynamic . I got the below using high chart what more I can do to get the above graph , please suggest .
[image]

Comment: currently I think this feature is not available. You make request here -> https://highcharts.uservoice.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done in Highcharts.

Refer to this **live demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9zr4ehw2/

It shows how to fill column bars with pattern.

You can create separate series for tops and bottoms of a pencil. Them use `stacking` to position columns on top of each other.